Angular how to prevent user from reload or go back using route guard
Angular how to prevent user from reload or go back using route guard. I have basically a component and i want to make sure that when user click on reload the page or go back, it will then return to my home page. I did try canDeactivate but doesnt seems to do the tricks.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfirmLeaveGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }
}

export class ReceiptComponent implements CanComponentDeactivate{
  private router = inject(Router);

  // Example method to prompt user before leaving
  canDeactivate(): boolean {
    // Example logic to prompt user with confirmation
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave? Your data may be lost.');
  }

      {
        path: 'receipt',
        loadComponent: () => import('receipt.component').then(({ ReceiptComponent }) => ReceiptComponent),
        canDeactivate: [ConfirmLeaveGuard]
      },


Apart from canDeactivate you also need to listen for the event window:beforeunload and then trigger canDeactivate also in the component.
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
canDeactivate(): any {  
    return component.canDeactivate();
}


this only work when user click on back but not working on user reloading the page.

@anscomooi you have to interact with the page only then the popup will show on refresh

i have tried and it wont work too.

@anscomooi try this stackblitz it works great!

Your code works. thank you
